# Pseudo graphics in C++

Tags: visual-c++

i looks for pseudo graphics lib for C++ under Visual Studio, lib like in TurboVision in Borland Turbo C++ or NCurser.. Or can i do it with standart c++ libs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/